# How to disable blogspot rss feeds from link of Blog ID?

Tags: rss, feed, blogspot

I want to disable blogspot.com feeds of  my blog. I turned off site feed from setting and working fine on link below

http://blogname.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default

http://blogname.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss

but not working(disabling) on feeds link using blog ID.

https://www.blogger.com/feeds/BLOG ID/posts/default

feeds still showing contents of my blog using link of Blog ID.

How can i disable this feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't - but with feeds turned off on the blog, you can only access the BlogID based feed URLs when you are logged in as an admin of the blog.